# Increase max file upload size in K8s Cluster deployed with Azure (Project in ASP.NET Core w/ C# and React)

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-aks

How do I increase the file upload size limit in Azure? It's capped at around 1MB. I tried looking through the various settings in the Azure portal and could not find anything. I believe the issue is with the cloud environment as I have no problems locally.

I have a web app in C# which uses ASP.NET Core and React with .tsx. When I run the program locally, I can upload files up to 28MB in size, which is the default limit for ASP.NET Core. However, when I deploy using Azure to the K8s cluster (Kubernetes Service), the web app can only upload files up to around 1MB in size.

I can upload a 984KB .jpg file. When I try uploading a 1,043KB .png (or anything larger), the response is

> 413 Request Entity Too Large
>
> nginx/1.17.7

I've seen [this question's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117392/net-core-128kb-file-size-limit-deployed-to-azure-app-service) which is

> The files object I was looping over in the posted code snippet was a IList type, which I was getting by casting the Request.Form.Files in the controller. Why I was doing this, I can't recall. Anyway, leaving the file list as the default IFormFileCollection that it gets bound to by MVC (the type on Request.Form.Files) seems to fix it. It also solved another problem I was having of certain file extensions not uploading.

However, I use `IFormFile` to upload throughout with no casting. The front end .tsx has a form with a `dropzone` input component. The change event `e.currentTarget.files` returns a `FileList`. The upload file command and controller both exclusively use `IFormFile` and the `IFileSystem`.

Comment: well, given this lack of detail, its impossible to give you a precise answer, azure doesnt limit the upload size, its either your application, or your ingress.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/814767/413-request-entity-too-large-in-nginx-with-client-max-body-size-set

Comment: There is a 1mb limit on storing Secrets or ConfigMaps - because of the underlying reliance on etcd - which has a 1mb limit for each entry. 

I suspect this may be the limit that you are running into - but your question doesn't provide sufficient information to diagnose this further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not provide much details, so I guess you're using a default setup that looks like this:

- You have one nginx ingress service
- Your apps are running behind this proxy

As you can see in your error message, the problem is NOT you asp.net core app but the nginx ingress in front of it.

To solve it, you've to configure your nginx ingress to allow bigger uploads.

In our configuration this looks like so

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 500m
```

So the steps to fix it:

- Update your ingress manifest file
- Apply changes using kubectl

Docs:

- https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic

Comment: I did a Find All on all file types in our entire solution for 'ingress', 'nginx', and 'kubernetes' and didn't get any relevant matches. We have a webpack.config.js file but no 'web.config' which a lot of posts mention. The appsettings.json's don't seem very helpful either. I am unsure where to look.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong place. It's outside of your app. It's part of your kubernetes setup. You'll have to talk to the one who did the cluster setup. Please note, I assume you're using Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).